# Index timestamp as date fail

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `datestamp timestamp not null` column in my PostgreSQL database and I would like to group by this field using only `Date`. I create index `create index date_idx_ondatestamp on log ((datestamp"::date));` but index never used by query. The only way to let query planners use the index is to convert the `datestamp` column from `timestamp` to `date` but I need to have time too.  Of course, I could create a Date column only for grouping but it seems redundant when we have an index cast that is not working.

How to cast index from timestamp to date and let query planner use it?

```
SELECT userid,
      datestamp"::date,
      count(*)
FROM log
GROUP BY userid, datestamp::date;
```

Comment: You query has to process **all** rows in the table. An index will not speed up this operation. But why the `group by` if you are not aggregating anything?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is just an example, I have added a count to make sense.  And what do you mean index will not speed up? It speeds up when I change column type to date.

Comment: I doubt that. Anyway, can you [edit] the question and show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output from the query where the index is used and from the query where it isn't?

Comment: Sorry guys but I don't understand your point? Are you saying that grouping by timestamp or date is not possible with an index? I will add query plans shortly.